# Wordpress Image editor error on admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem, i made a new skin for wp, and since that, when i place and image in my post, and click on the edit image logo, nothing happens, it wont edit the image it opens my site in the pop up window.

What do am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I found the image url and had a look according to firefox it "contains error". The error appears to be whitespace related, don't know where it came from but I came across the suggestion to add a `ob_clean();` before outputting the image and this worked for me.

edit the file /wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php and in the function `wp_stream_image()` add 
  `ob_clean();` right before the `switch?  statement. After this the image loaded and the editor seems to work, hooray.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I put the ob_clean(); on this location:

```
function wp_stream_image( $image, $mime_type, $post_id ) {
        if ( $image instanceof WP_Image_Editor ) {

            ob_clean();

            /**
             * Filters the WP_Image_Editor instance for the image to be streamed to the browser.
             *
             * @since 3.5.0
```